# Unable to boot directly to Mac OS X

Tags: windows-7, macos, macbook, boot-camp

I was trying to install Windows 7 on my Macbook pro using bootcamp, after creating partition I found out that I missed my DVD at office desk.

Later I deleted the partition, but when I restart the macbook it kept telling that

> "No bootable device found"

even after deleting the partition, I'm expecting it to boot directly to Mac OSX.

Is there any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you delete the partition? Through Mac OSX?

Try holding option as your MacBook boots up (before the Apple logo shows). See if there's a choice for Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me, mac osx not showing, only showing windows... I've never ha problems and I've been using bootcamp for 8 months now, today I was using win 7 and upgraded my bootcamp to 3.1, restarted and that's when mac osx wasnt showing up anymore, only windows and DVD, wonder what happened!! I'll try disk utility with the snow leopard DVD, repair disk might fix it...